# RuntimeBinderException on .net core 3.1 using dynamic list on razor component

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, blazor-server-side

I am using .NET core 3.1 with EF and blazor to try and render some razor components. The scenario is - I have a large number of possible test result types (all of which are derived from a base test result class). I am creating a razor component for each type of test result, which will then be called from a number of different master results page (depending on the parent object). This is all working fine with the service below, which implements a single type of test:

```
public async Task<IList<TestRowWaterAbsorption>> GetTestList(string parentObject, int parentID)
        {
            var listDetails = new List<TestRowWaterAbsorption>();

            switch (parentObject)
            {
                case "TestContainer":
                     listDetails = await _context.TestRowWaterAbsorption.Where(t=>t.TestContainerID == parentID).ToListAsync();
                    break;
                case "TestRun":
                     listDetails = await _context.TestRowWaterAbsorption.Where(t => t.TestRunID == parentID).ToListAsync();
                    break;
                case "Item":
                     listDetails = await _context.TestRowWaterAbsorption.Where(t => t.TestItemID == parentID).ToListAsync();
                    break;
                default:
                    return listDetails = null;

            }


            return listDetails;
        }
    }
```

However it seems ridiculous to write a separate method for each possible type of test. I am hoping to write a more generic method that implements the logic above (ie. selects the appropriate ID to query the database for), and pass in the object type (in the example above this would be the TestRowWaterAbsorption object) and then choose the appropriate context and return a list of the appropriate type.

I have tried the following, which seems to return the list that I want

```
:

        public List<dynamic> GetListAsync(string parentObject, int parentID, string testObjectType)
        {
            var listDetails = new List<dynamic>();
            IEnumerable listSet = _context.Set(Type.GetType(testObjectType));

            switch (parentObject)
            {

                case "TestContainer":
                    //listDetails = await _context.TestRowWaterAbsorption.Where(t => t.TestContainerID == parentID).ToListAsync();
                    listDetails = ((IEnumerable)listSet).Cast<dynamic>().Where(t => t.TestContainerID == parentID).ToList();
                    break;
                case "TestRun":
                    //listDetails = await _context.TestRowWaterAbsorption.Where(t => t.TestRunID == parentID).ToListAsync();
                    listDetails = ((IEnumerable)listSet).Cast<dynamic>().Where(t => t.TestRunID == parentID).ToList();
                    break;
                case "Item":
                    //listDetails = await _context.TestRowWaterAbsorption.Where(t => t.TestItemID == parentID).ToListAsync();
                    //IQueryable<Object> listSet = _context.Set(Type.GetType(parentObject)).Where(t => t.TestItemID == parentID);
                    listDetails = ((IEnumerable)listSet).Cast<dynamic>().Where(t => t.TestItemID == parentID).ToList();
                    break;
                default:
                    return listDetails;

            }

            return listDetails;
        }
```

Which required the use of the following extension method:

```
namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class DbContextExtensions
    {
        public static IQueryable<Object> Set(this DbContext _context, Type t)
        {
            return (IQueryable<Object>)_context.GetType().GetMethod("Set").MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(_context, null);
        }



    }
}
```

However when I try and view the razor component, I get the following error

> RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following
>   methods or properties:
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(int,
>   string)' and
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RenderTreeBuilder.AddContent(int,
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderFragment)'

Looking at the objects in debug doesn't seem to be giving me any clue - the list looks to be typed correctly, and has the expected number of elements.

The .razor file is as below, and I get the unhandled exception on the open { following the foreach statement

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web
@using KookaburraLab.Models
@using KookaburraLab.Services
@using System.Threading.Tasks
@inject ITestRowService testRowService



<h4>Testing generic method using generic option</h4>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Status
            </th>
            <th>
                Description
            </th>
            <th>
                Initial Mass
            </th>
            <th>
                Avg Thickness
            </th>
            <th>
                Density
            </th>
            <th>
                Initial Moisture
            </th>
            <th>
                Mass after Soak
            </th>
            <th>
                Water Absorption
            </th>
            <th>
                Item ID
            </th>
            <th>
                Sample ID
            </th>


            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @if (testRowList == null)
    {
        <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
    }
    else
    {
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in testRowList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.TestRowStatus
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.TestRowSampleDescription
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.InitialMass
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.AverageThickness
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.Density
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.InitialMoisture
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.MassAfterSoak
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.WaterAbsorption
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.TestItemID
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @item.TestRowSampleID
                    </td>


                    <td>

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    }
    </table>


@code {

    IEnumerable<dynamic> testRowList;
    [Parameter]
    public int parentID { get; set; }
    [Parameter]
    public string parentType { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        testRowList = testRowService.GetListAsync(parentType,parentID,"KookaburraLab.Models.TestRowWaterAbsorption");
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I've found a workaround, but its horrible. If I serialize the dynamic object and then deserialize it into a strongly typed object on the razor component, the component works as expected. If there is a better way of doing this I would love to know it through!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql